addEventListener("offline", update) not working on Firefox
Working on Chrome but not Firefox
addEventListener is not the issue, it's updating offline/online status.
If someone can do the snippet, anyone can test it.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="user_status"></p>
<script>
const user_status = document.getElementById("user_status");

function updateOnlineStatus(event) {
 let condition = navigator.onLine ? "online" : "offline";
 user_status.innerHTML = "Status: " + condition;
 console.log("Event: " + event.type, " Status: " + condition);
}
window.addEventListener('online',  updateOnlineStatus);
window.addEventListener('offline', updateOnlineStatus);

updateOnlineStatus({});
</script>
</body>
</html>


You're going to have to be a little more detailed in how you're testing your code. (especially as the navigator.onLine property does not tell you whether the user has internet access, it only checks whether there's any sort of network available)

It tells me if I'm connected to WiFi or mobile data, and when they are up or down again. So it tells if I'm online or not which is what I want.

No, it doesn't: If your WIFI connection works but your router has no WAN connection, then you're online as far as navigator.onLine can see. Despite the fact that you're 100% not able to connect to anything except the router itself. onLine only means you have a connection to at least one network, it says nothing about whether that network "goes anywhere".

I see. I disconnected my fiber just to prove it. And it's true.
